# Updating directive whenever input change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

First off, new to angularJS so sorry if this question is trivial but my end goal is to change my template whenever a new markdown file is inputed. So  right now my directive is looking like this:

```
app.directive('markdown', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true, 
    scope: {
        fileinput: '='
    }, 
    compile: function(elem, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe("fileinput", function() {
            elem.replaceWith(marked(markdownString));
        });

    }
  }
});
```

My html is looking like is looking like this

```
<markDown md="test1.txt"></markDown>
<input type="file" name="filename" id="fileinput" ng-model="input">
```

Where test1.txt is a markdown file that I convert viat the marked() function into html. Below is how I read in test1.txt.

```
$("#fileinput").change(function (e) {
      if (e.target.files != undefined) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            markdownString = e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0));
      }
    });
```

I can read in a file perfectly, but the the directive will replace the HTML before I have opened and read the file, which is fine, but I want to update the directive and have it run again whenever I input a file. I've tried both attrs.$observe and scope.$watch, but neither seem to be working for me, perhaps I am just writing them incorrectly?

Thanks in advanced!

**Edit!**
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vQzKJ/32/)
With the below help I was able to get the input to chanve, but now it's on a delay, not quite what I wanted. Upload files a couple times to see what I mean. Thank you

Comment: Put this into a jsfiddle or plunker and post the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [lot of talk](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1375) about supporting/not supporting `input type="file"` in angular, but they do not support binding to it. The key issue seems to be that you can only read file input properties and Angular's core binding concept is 2-way.

tldr:

You can't use an `ng-model` for this, but you can [do it manually](http://jsfiddle.net/neilsarkar/vQzKJ/).

Comment: Thanks for your swift help, but it seems to update on a delay of one input. Here is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vQzKJ/32/). When you add a file it seems to update the previous one. This is so close to the result I want but just slightly off!